# How to target Kindle Fire from Visual Studio Cordova Tools?

Tags: cordova, kindle-fire, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to target Kindle Fire from Visual Studio Cordova Tools?  I've finally gotten my Cordova tools all working after a few days of trying.  Really it was the release of Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 that got everything working before that I had a lot of trouble.

I've been using visual studio for a long time but I'm new to Cordova.  I've seen articles about Cordova working with Kindle Fire but I'm curious on how to get this to work all the way through Visual Studio.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, Visual Studio Cordova only supports Windows, Windows Phone, Android and iOS.